# default_storage.exists extremely slow and frequently times out

Tags: python, django, amazon-s3, django-storage

We have just migrated a Django project to Heroku and put all of our media and static files on Amazon S3 (using django-storages and s3-boto).

Despite everything I've heard about Amazon S3 being very fast, and turning up very few results on slow performance, our image loading has slowed to an absolute crawl and frequently times out. An example of the code that is timing out is this property on one of our models, which tries to select an appropriate image, ultimately falling back to returning `None`:

```
@property
def photo(self):
    """Transparently serve the best available image for templates"""
    if self.model_shot.storage.exists(self.model_shot.name):
        return self.model_shot
    elif self.image.storage.exists(self.image.name):
        return self.image
    else:
        return None
```

When I tested on a model which was causing problems, I tried this:

```
$ heroku run python manage.py shell
...
>>> design = Design.objects.get(pk=10210)
>>> design.photo
```

This command caused the shell to hang for several seconds before finally returning an `ImageFieldFile` object. Subsequent calls to it returned instantaneously, which makes me believe the result is cached.

My question is, what is the best way to handle this? I have heard a lot about using CloudFront in situations like this, but this is definitely not due to high traffic (shouldn't have basically any traffic on our site yet). Some other caching framework? Something else entirely?

Most of the images in question are 1000x1000 px at least.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Switching to CloudFront completely solved this issue, and was relatively easy (no code changes just more monkeying around with the Amazon Console), so I decided to answer my own question.

## tl;dr Do not serve files directly from S3; set up CloudFront.

---

#### Serving an S3 Bucket via CloudFront

**Step 0:** If you haven't already, make sure your bucket name complies with the ["best practices"](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/BucketRestrictions.html) for naming buckets. They don't necessarily make this obvious in all the places they should, but a bad bucket name can completely break its interoperability with other Amazon Web Services. The best thing to do is name your bucket something all lowercase that's not too long (<= 60 characters or so).

**Step 1:** In order to get CloudFront to serve files from your bucket, you need to set it up as if to serve a static website. You can do this on the Amazon AWS console from your bucket's `Permissions` tab. Amazon has several places where there are instructions/documentation for this; IMO the clearest are [these](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/gettingstarted/latest/swh/getting-started-create-cfdist.html). ***IMPORTANT***: Make sure you set up the Default Root Object to `index.html` -- that file doesn't even have to exist, but that setting *does*.

**Step 1.5 [possibly optional]:** Make sure the permissions on your bucket are correct. Even though I was serving files from S3 no problem, changing to CloudFront to serve them turned everything into a **403: Access Forbidden** error. If in doubt, and your files are not sensitive, you can right click on folders of your bucket in the AWS Console and click `Make Public`. ***WARNING***: This can be a **very time intensive** process, and for some stupid reason (even though it's server side) your browser session has to stay open. Do this first and don't close your session. For our bucket, this took about 16 hours. :/

**Step 2:** Go to the `Amazon CloudFront` section in the AWS Console and click the `Create Distribution` button. Make it a web distribution (default) and use the domain you generated by setting your bucket up for static web distribution in the previous step as the origin. Again, IMO, [these](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/gettingstarted/latest/swh/getting-started-create-cfdist.html) are the clearest and most straightforward instructions in the AWS docs. You can leave just about everything default here. Once it's created, just wait until it's listed on the console as "Deployed".

**Step 3:** Configure your app to serve from CloudFront rather than S3. This is the easiest part because the URLs are transparently moved from `https://bucketname.s3.amazonaws.com/path` to `https://somerandomstring.cloudfront.net/path` (bonus: you can set up the latter as a `CNAME` record to point to something like `media.yourdomain.tld`; we didn't do this so I won't go into it here). Since I'm using Django with a combination of `django-storages` and `s3-boto`, this ended up being a simple matter of [setting up that Cloudfront domain in `settings.py`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24698876/2588818):

```
AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN = 'd2ynhpzeiwwiom.cloudfront.net'
```

And that's it! With these changes, all of our speed woes went away, and our media-rich pages (6-20 MP worth of images per page) suddenly load faster than ever!

Answer (score 2):

I encountered similar problems on a production site as it scaled up. What I'd recommend is using a storage backend that can maintain its own copy of all meta-information about your S3 files. The best such project is probably [MimicDB](https://github.com/nathancahill/mimicdb), though you can also check out what I've done with a [modified django-storages](https://github.com/mstarinteractive/django-s3storage). That way, metadata queries like `.exists()`, `.url`, etc. are answered instantly from the local cache.

Also, make sure that you are generally just getting the URL or other metadata of the `image` objects, and not using any code that would cause your server to needlessly fetch the actual image data. What I like to do when setting this sort of thing up is modify the S3 wrapper (e.g. boto) so it will log every raw S3 REST request, and then test the site and make sure that simply viewing web pages on the site doesn't cause any S3 requests from the web server.

Comment: Thank you for another idea I hadn't considered. In the absence of other answers yesterday I went ahead and set up CloudFront, which I'm going to finish hooking up this AM. Will try this next if that doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Set **AWS_PRELOAD_METADATA = False** (default value is False), to avoid loading all the files metadata from the bucket to memory. This will not only boost the waiting time of the request, it will also reduce the memory usage.
In my case the memory usage got reduced from ~1.5 GB to 5-6MB and the time reduced from 60s to 4-5s only.

Original answer:
[Why does default_storate.exists() with django-storages with S3Boto backend cause a memory error with a large S3 bucket?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21120825/why-does-default-storate-exists-with-django-storages-with-s3boto-backend-cause)

Comment: This fixed my problem, time went from 25s to 0.2s.  Thank!