# Updated MEDIA_URL not reflected in ImageField url

Tags: django, amazon-s3, django-storage

I'm trying to move from serving files on Amazon S3 to Amazon CloudFront, so I updated my `settings.py`. Previously, I had this:

```
S3_URL = 'http://{}.s3.amazonaws.com'.format(AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME)
STATIC_URL = S3_URL + STATIC_DIRECTORY
MEDIA_URL = S3_URL + MEDIA_DIRECTORY
```

I updated this as follows:

```
#S3_URL = 'http://{}.s3.amazonaws.com'.format(AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME)
S3_URL = 'http://d2ynhpzeiwwiom.cloudfront.net'
```

In the console, the settings are updated:

```
>>> from django.conf import settings
>>> settings.MEDIA_URL
'http://d2ynhpzeiwwiom.cloudfront.net/media/'
```

But not on my model's `ImageField`:

```
>>> design.image.url
'https://bucketname.s3.amazonaws.com/media/images/designs/etc/etc'
```

What gives? Where is the old information still stored and how do I flush it out?

Comment: Did you restart the server ?

Comment: I figured it out -- answering myself in just a sec

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whoops, turns out the `FileField.url` property doesn't use `MEDIA_URL`. According to [the Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.fields.files.FieldFile.url):

> **FieldFile.url**
>
> A read-only property to access the file’s relative URL by calling the url() method of the underlying Storage class.

In my case, the underlying storage class, was `S3BotoStorage` provided by `django-storages`. As noted by [this now-deprecated fork](https://github.com/incuna/django-storages-cloudfront), this was previously not supported, but can now be done by adding the following to `settings.py`:

```
AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN = 'd2ynhpzeiwwiom.cloudfront.net'
```

Now it works like a charm:

```
>>> design.image.url
u'https://d2ynhpzeiwwiom.cloudfront.net/media/images/designs/etc/etc'
```

Comment: [Docs on `AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN`](https://django-storages.readthedocs.io/en/latest/backends/amazon-S3.html#cloudfront)