# Error using django-compressor and AWS CloudFront

Tags: django, boto, amazon-cloudfront, django-storage, django-compressor

I've been successfully using `django-compressor` and `django-storages` to manage the compression and deployment of my static files in Django 1.6. I'm now trying to use AWS CloudFront to serve my static files.

I followed the instructions here [default_storage.exists extremely slow and frequently times out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24685790/default-storage-exists-extremely-slow-and-frequently-times-out) and my `settings.py` file looks like this:

```
COMPRESS_ENABLED = True

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(
    os.path.dirname(
        os.path.dirname(
            os.path.abspath(__file__))), 'static')
COMPRESS_ROOT = STATIC_ROOT

COMPRESS_OFFLINE = True

COMPRESS_URL = "https://compressor-test.s3.amazonaws.com/"
STATIC_URL = COMPRESS_URL

COMPRESS_STORAGE = 'mysite.storage.CachedS3BotoStorage'
STATICFILES_STORAGE = COMPRESS_STORAGE

AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = 'compressor-test'
AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN = '1234567.cloudfront.net'
```

But i'm getting the following error:

```
Exception Type:     UncompressableFileError
Exception Value:    

'https://1234567.cloudfront.net/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css' isn't accessible via COMPRESS_URL ('https://compressor-test.s3.amazonaws.com/') and can't be compressed
```

Do I need to point the COMPRESS_URL at CloudFront?

Comment: Can u reach the file manually?

Comment: Yes, if i paste the full url in the address bar it opens the right file.

Comment: I dont remember why, but i remember now this problem is asked in stackoverflow before. U may re-search again.

Answer (score 1):

Try pointing your COMPRESS_URL to cloudfront, should do the trick

Answer (score 0):

In order to write static files to S3, but read from Cloudfront, use:

`AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN = 'yourdistribution.cloudfront.net'`

[Related django-compressor issue on GitHub](https://github.com/django-compressor/django-compressor/issues/187).